# Match graphic tablet active area to monitor subarea in a dual monitor setup

Tags: multi-monitor, xinput, tablet

I have a graphic tablet with a pen recognized by xinput as `UC-LOGIC Tablet WP8060U Pen`.

The tablet active area has 4:3 proportions.

I have two monitors: 2560x1440 (16:9) on the left and 1440x900 (16:10) on the right.

I'd like to limit the tablet pen to a 4:3 area centered on the left monitor, therefore a 1920x1440 window with an offset from the left border of 320px.

I have trouble understanding what to use for the commands

```
xinput set-prop "UC-LOGIC Tablet WP8060U Pen" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix VALUES HERE"
xinput set-prop "UC-LOGIC Tablet WP8060U Pen" "Evdev Axis Calibration" xmin xmax ymin ymax
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I solved it:

- the default `Evdev Axis Calibration` is fine (unplug & plug to delete previous values set by `xinput set-prop`)
- the transformation matrix should be

`width/tot_width 0 x_offset/tot_width
0 1 0
0 0 1`

In my case width is 1920, tot_width = 2560+1440=4000, x_offset=320, therefore the complete command becomes

`xinput set-prop "UC-LOGIC Tablet WP8060U Pen" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0.48 0 0.08 0 1 0 0 0 1`

Comment: I'm not sure how to read these errors: X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  20